# Javascript FadeToggle not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

if i click the reply button then reply form open. However, it have a problem
code only work first element

[image]

After that
[image]

Button code

```
<div class="reply-button bubble-ornament blue" id="replybutton">
                    <i class="icon-action-undo reply-icon"></i>
                  </div>
```

Js code;

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#replybutton').click(function () {
         $('#replyform').fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: I cannot see element with id `replyform` in the `html`.

Comment: You're probably using the same ID (`replybutton`) for multiple elements. IDs are meant to be unique, use class names.

Answer (score 2):

The ID should be a unique per document. In your case `$('#replybutton')` can only be attached once. Please use `$('.replybutton')` as class selector and modify your HTML accordingly.

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: well, I used to comment but was told in another post put as an answer so that the question is answered. It's really unfair to downvote.

Comment: people referring this post come here in the intention to get answer , They may get confused by this . Make sure to maintain the website standard . Thanks